# How big the spark stream window could be?

Tags: apache-spark, stream, spark-streaming

I have some data flows need to be calculated. I am thinking about use spark stream to do this job. But there is one thing I am not sure and feel worry about.

My requirements is like :

Data comes in as CSV files every 5 minutes. I need report on data of recent 5 minutes, 1 hour and 1 day. So If I setup a spark stream to do this calculation. I need a interval as 5 minutes. Also I need to setup two window 1 hour and 1 day.

Every 5 minutes there will be 1GB data comes in. So the one hour window will calculate 12GB (60/5) data and the one day window will calculate 288GB(24*60/5)  data.

I do not have much experience on spark. So this worries me.

1. Can spark handle such big window ?
2. How much RAM do I need to calculation those 288 GB data?  More than 288 GB RAM? (I know this may depend on my disk I/O, CPU and the calculation pattern. But I just want some estimated answer based on experience)
3. If calculation on one day / one hour data is too expensive in stream. Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: This use case sounds a lot more like a combination of streaming with batch. I would not recommend a window over a day of data.

Comment: @maasg Absolutely, agree. I would recommend to have three different jobs. Probably that will have the same logic and they could reuse the same code. The first one - is streaming job for processing 5-minute intervals. And two batch jobs which are executed on schedule (every hour and every 24 hours). As for memory for processing 288GB, it depends on operations, partitions sizes, etc.

Comment: In worst case I believe you will need more that 288GB.

Comment: Very appreciate for all the comments. I also feel not good to make a window longer than one day. But it is just a feeling. I am expecting some very specific reasons or proof showing why that is not a good idea. Can anyone know this？ Or it is just a unprovable feeling to all?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?  I was reviewing reduceByKeyAndWindow()  here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html and it sounds like it would use constant space, so it sounds viable to me.  But I can'd find info online either.

Comment: reduceByKeyAndWindow() seems indeed a very viable path even for big datasets. 

Have you tried it out?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541903/kafka-streams-with-large-sliding-windows