# Kafka Streams with large sliding windows

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, sliding-window

I need to show usage stats at any points on time for last 3 months, 6 months and 1 year. I am planning to use the KStream sliding windows for the durations mentioned above. Most of the examples I see are using durations in minutes or seconds. I would like to know is that OK to use the bigger time duration for sliding windows? Any performance impact? Any specific configuration It should use to get optimum performance?

Thanks,
Jinu

Answer (score 1):

It will really depend on the density of the data and what kind of aggregations you are doing. It could end up with very large number of windows updating and not closing since the end time is so far out. Also if it is too heavy I am not sure the state stores could handle it. But with the correct load and retention times I don't see an obvious reason it wouldn't work.

Edit: If you do end up trying it I would be very interested in seeing how it works out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The data is huge..it could even be around a million data per day.
How about giving a grace period of 1 day for a 6 months window..That would probably results in around 180 windows..What I am interested in the window period is the total count and the time of the last arrived record for a key..Is it possible to write an aggregation logic so that only one record exist for window?

Comment: If you are interested in only counts or last values/time it should be no problem. I would suggest doing some upstream aggregation to lighten the load, but that might not even be necessary. Sliding windows adjust be the record. What you want is probably a hopping TimeWindow with a 6 month window and a 1 day advance. There should be no issues with that (https://forum.confluent.io/t/sliding-windows-vs-hopping-windows/882) is a good explanation of the difference of hopping and sliding windows

Comment: Yes. Makes sense to use a hoping window for my use case. Few points i would like to clarify here.
1. I need to retrieve the data from the application. Hence i planning to use a persistent window store for the same. Will the window store create the change log topics automatically? If so will the windows persists over the application restart? 
As the default retention period for hoping window is 1 day, i would probably make use of that, but can i set the same i day retention for window store as well?